# How to use mattes/migrate in golang?

Tags: postgresql, go, migration, sqlx

I've been trying to use the [mattes/migrate](https://github.com/mattes/migrate) package but I can't seem to get it to actually do anything. The database runs on postgres and I interact with it through [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx).

I've gone through the readme on github, and applied the following code:

```
// use synchronous versions of migration functions ...
allErrors, ok := migrate.UpSync("postgres://<my_url_string>", "./app/database/migrations")
if !ok {
  fmt.Println("Oh no ...")
  // do sth with allErrors slice
}
```

My schema is initiated like this:

```
//sqlx's initiated DB is imported in the database package

func SyncSchemas() {
  database.DB.MustExec(schema)
}

var schema =
  `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS examples (
     created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
     deleted_at text DEFAULT NULL,
     id UUID PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
   );`

type Example struct {
  ID            string      `json:"id" db:"id"`
  CreatedAt     time.Time   `json:"created_at" db:"created_at"`
  DeletedAt     *time.Time  `json:"deleted_at" db:"deleted_at"` 
}
```

It runs without error, but that's all it seems to be doing at the moment. Shouldn't it keep track of my schemas or something? I previously used [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) as my ORM, and there I just had to run autoMigrate() on a schema and it automatically created and applied migrations as I changed the schema. I would like the same functionality with mattes/migrate, but I can't seem to find an example or tutorial which shows how to use it.

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: What is directory structure where is you migration resides?

Comment: In an empty folder "migrations" within the database folder where the first code snippet resides: app/database/migrations. The schema is in another folder: app/example/model/example.go

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion in whenever you code in Golang is to **`check the errors`** do it in this way

```
if allErrors, ok := migrate.UpSync("postgres://<my_url_string>", "./migrations"); !ok {
  fmt.Println("Oh no ...", ok)
  // do sth with allErrors slice
}
```

As I don't know what is your error at least in this way you can check what your error is.

Comment: There isn't an error, that's the problem. The error reporting works as it had thrown when I had a typo in the database url and it couldn't find the migrations folder at first. Now it doesn't have any errors, yet still doesn't do anything. Aren't I supposed to declare my schemas to mattes/migrate or something instead so it can keep track of changes?